# Links which HOMFLY homology distinguish but the HOMFLY polynomial does not.

Tags: knot-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, reference-request

> Does anyone know of a pair of different links which the HOMFLY polynomial does not distinguish, but HOMFLY homology does? Or does there exist such a pair of links?

I'm assuming there does exist such a pair, but have never seen it. I've been looking for this for a few days and have had no luck finding or computing such an example. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A related question is http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25747/is-there-a-non-trivial-knot-with-trivial-homfly-polynomial

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although $5_1$ and $10_{132}$ cannot be distinguished by Jones, Alexander and (uncolored) HOMFLY-PT polynomials, their HOMFLY homologies do tell them. (See the [review](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6075) by Gukov-Saberi.)

In addition, some mutant pairs can be distinguished by Khovanov homology. (See the [paper](http://xxx.lanl.gov/pdf/math/0301312v1.pdf) by Wehrli.)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: However, the colored Jones polynomials do distinguish the $5_1$ and $10_132$ knots (according to the Knot Atlast).